# string transceive between windows phone and intel galileo

Tags: python, string, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, intel-galileo

Thai concept on my project is that windows phone and intel galileo will exchange string messages over bluetooth.
I was thinking to use python, but i am open to any other programming language.

Do you have any samples how to do it from the perspective of the galileo ?

Answer (score 0):

[What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

I've never worked with a Galileo before, but [this page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/do-it-yourself/galileo-maker-quark-board.html) indicates that it's "hardware and software pin-compatible with shields designed for the Arduino Uno R3". This sounds like a great place to start.

The [product data sheet](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-21835) for the Galileo indicates that it doesn't have bluetooth on board (although you can use a mPCI card), and also indicates that you use the Arduino software development tools.

I'd recommend starting out by looking for an [arduino bluetooth tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+bluetooth+tutorial). The first link looks like a good one.  Since the Galileo is a relatively new product I wouldn't expect to find any Galileo-specific tutorials or examples at this point. Maybe you can write the first one?